# Remove pointer-events from background-image

Tags: css

Consider a ***translucid*** `background-image` blocking the `pointer-events` of css links underneath it. I would like to make the links work even beneath this image.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If one element overlaps another you can't click it, simple.

You can put the links on top of the overlay, but you will lose the effect on those links. It's not classy, but I guess it would work.

```
a {
    position: relative; /* set them relative, keeping their position */
    z-index: 1000;      /* set z-index to move it in front */
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sure. But I rather loose the links than the translucid fx above them. It's a very minimal particular situation. I just wondered if this could be possible somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so!
generally one of the oldest image theft methods was putting image behind a transparent image.
but if it is very important to you you can make hot spots on that image with some usual methods such as html image map or using some of the svg capabilities.
   and if there is effects like shadow or something like this you can use css3 to make them with code

Comment: Yes it should solve the problem unless my links weren't moving/rolling behind this image. I could move the maps/graphics also, but this would be unnecessarily intensive. And I just can't use CSS shadows due to other minimal rendering issues, would mess the layout. But thanks for helping!

Comment: sorry for late response, if you can get me a fiddle or sample maybe i can help